# InputStream reading

Tags: java, inputstream

Good night in my timezone.

I am building an http bot, and when i receive the response from the server i want to make two things.First is to print the body of the response and because i know that the body of the response is of the type TEXT/HTML the second thing that i make is to parse the response through a html parser(in this specific case NekoHtml).
Snippet of code :

```
    //Print the first call
    printResponse(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    document = new InputSource(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    parser.setDocument(document);
```

The problem is when i run the first line (printResponse) the second line will throw an exception.
Now the questions-> This happens because the InputStream can only be read one time ?every time that we read from the inputstream the bytes are cleaned?
How can we read more that one time the content from the inputstream ?

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the response from the server into a byte array. You can then create a ByteArrayInputStream to repeatedly read the bytes.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what *Ted Hopp* said take a look at [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library. You will find:

- `IOUtils.toString(urlConnection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8")` utility method that takes an input stream, fully reads it and returns a string in a given encoding
- [`TeeInputStream`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html) is an `InputStream` decorator that takes will copy every read byte and copy it into a given output stream as well.

Should work:

```
 InputStream is = new TeeInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream(), System.out);
```

Comment: +1 for TeeInputStream--if you care at all about performance under load and/or scaling this thing--whatever it is--do everything possible to avoid buffering entire pages in memory.

Comment: I don't see how TeeInputStream fixes things. OP wants to read the data twice, not send it to a second destination. The example would copy everything read from `is` to System.out, which would be rather useless for parsing.

Comment: @TedHopp, well it was just an example. The OP says: "First is to print the body of the response and [...] the second thing that i make is to parse the response through a html parser" - so I thought redirecting to `System.out` is a good start. Of course he can redirect to `ByteArrayOutputStream` as well. The whole point was to avoid loading the whole thing into memory as @RyanStewart suggested.

Answer (score 0):

As Ted Hopp said:

```
    byte [] bytes = new byte[urlConnection.getInputStream().available()];
    printResponse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    document = new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
    parser.setDocument(document);
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `available()` to get the input length; the entire document may not be currently available, especially over a network connection. Use the content-length header of the response. If that's missing (or you think it's unreliable), use a ByteArrayOutputStream and read in a loop (using a buffer byte array) until you reach the end of the stream.